# How to load an HTML page in Qt5 WebEngineView using utf-8 encoding?

Tags: html, c++, encoding, qt5, qwebengineview

I have an html page, which I am loading into my Qt5 application using QWebEngineView like this:

```
QWebEngineView* webEngineView = new QWebEngineView();
webEngineView->setUrl("index.html");
```

I use UTF-8 characters in my html file, such as "…" (#x2026; in html), which show up as "?" in the application.

The html file contains 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` and I have tried using `webEngineView->settings()->setDefaultTextEncoding("utf-8");` to no avail.

Can anyone help me display these characters?

Comment: You should also show contain of your index.html.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.

While I was trying to make a small workable example of my index.html I realised that the issue is not in `setUrl()`, but in a loalisation function in my JS file, which was setting the encoding to ASCII. So was looking for a solution in exactly the wrong place :)

Comment: Its my personal experience, when ever I try to create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, most of time that process itself solve my doubt/question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that the issue was not in the `setUrl()` method, but in a localisation function I had in my JS file. That function was explicitly setting the encoding to ASCII instead of UTF-8.

The `setUrl()` method of QWebEngineView seems to load the html file with the correct encoding without it being explicitly specified in the C++ code.